# What does initialization hell mean?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have recently completed a custom vector container implementation. I tried to mimic the original vector implementation as much as I can. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/CaglayanDokme/CPP-Exercises/blob/main/Containers/VectorContainer.h).

After publishing it on a community platform, someone commented about one of the overloads of the fill constructors. The signatures of these overloads are as follows

```
explicit Vector(const size_type numOfElements, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
Vector(const size_type numOfElements, const value_type& fillValue, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

The guy says that the second one could be a gate to ***initialization hell***. And then, I searched for the term but couldn't find a proper result.

What does initialization hell mean, and how does it occur?

Comment: You should really ask the person in question but I notice the second isn't explicit so depending on the value type, `Vector{1, 2}` is suspicious.

Comment: @chris [Try it out.](https://godbolt.org/z/4vcE33qb8) Looks similar to me :(

Comment: Right, you get the same thing because `vector` itself is "broken".  `vector{1, 2}` isn't calling the above constructor, but instead the `std::initializer_list` constructor.  Instead of having a vector of 1 element with the value of 2, you have a vector with 2 elements, 1 and 2.

Comment: Sorry, I said `explicit` and then didn't use it. I meant more like `return {1, 2}` etc. where it gets even more hairy making sure it does what you think with no context.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It's only broken if you think `{}` should magically do whatever you're thinking [somehow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM).  `{}` constructors aways construct from a list of data, and `()` always constructs via alternative constructions.  This has consistently worked for me for all C and C++ data types.